# Kubernetes Spark Cores Allocation issue

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Spark Allocates Cores it is not fully utilize them,as far as Kubernetes will be concerned, the AgentPool in the Cluster will have plenty of CPU Resources to do its work,Spark will be concerned, there will be 0 available cores to do work. If there are 0 Cores available for Work, then Spark will send Drivers and Applications into a WAITING status. So Spark will think it doesnt have the Resources to do any work, and KUbernetes will think there are plenty of Resources to do the work. what will be solution for this issue.

Comment: Haven't got your issue, can you provide the example?

Comment: I didnt fully understand your question. Please edit it and Provide your current issue and expected behavior.

Comment: think  that it has 80 Cores available. If 81 pieces of work came into the Cluster right now, 80 Items will allocate a Driver ( which will allocate 1 Core for itself ) - and the 81st item will go into a WAITING status. Since all the Cores are allocated, NONE of the Drivers will fire a RUNNING Application since Spark doesnt think there are any Cores available for work to be done.

Comment: Then seems like you're looking for the Dynamic Allocation on Kubernetes which is currently not added to the main Apache Spark release. You need to install [External Shuffle Service](https://apache-spark-on-k8s.github.io/userdocs/running-on-kubernetes.html#dynamic-executor-scaling) and [configure Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation) appropriately. As well there is already merged to `master` [feature](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/24817) to support dynamic allocation without the External Shuffle Service.

Comment: thanks for the idea, any steps to implement it

Comment: I would prefer to go with the second, for that fetch Spark sources from `master` and [build](https://github.com/apache/spark#building-spark) it locally and build the [Docker image](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#docker-images). Following the PR mentioned above you need to set `spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled=true`. Note that it is not released yet and still experimental.
I hope it to be released in 3.0, until that would prefer either live with that, or control it externally, or provide your own Spark customization.

Comment: Thanks for your time, any sample files you have or any exxample links , i am new to it please help

Comment: Everything I can refer is [that PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/24817). You need to experiment with that. Today I've seen that it is already announced to be included to the Spark 3.0 release. But no guides, docs and examples yet available. I plan to try it out as well, but cannot promise you when. Share your experience here if you try this out.